# How to get list of changed properties in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5, change-tracking

I can easily get EntityEntry and it's status:

```
EntityEntry<Customer> entry = dbContext.Entry(customer);
```

How do I get list of changed properties for EntityEntry?

I have something like this:

```
entry.CurrentValues.Properties
    .Where(prop => changedEntry.CurrentValues[prop] != changedEntry.OriginalValues[prop])
    .Select(prop => new 
    {
        Property = prop, 
        Value = changedEntry.CurrentValues[prop] 
    });
```

but it does not support ValueComparers.

Comment: There is a similar older question, but the accepted answer is not acceptable by me, because it does not support columns mapped to fields, value converters, etc

Comment: What is not acceptable and why? Mention that in the question itself. Besides, ValueComparers aren't changed properties. They're something that's used to load properties whether they are changed or not. You won't find them in the change tracker, you'll find them in the DbSet's metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in the following way:

```cs
entry.Properties
    .Where(prop => prop.IsModified)
    .Select(prop => new
    {
        Property = prop.Metadata,
        Value = prop.CurrentValue,
    });
```

Other methods needs accessing EF Core's `Internal` namespace.

Comment: are you sure `DetectChanges()` is required? 
I have seen that  `DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()` tries to call DetectChanges(). Not sure about `DbContext.Entry()`, however.

Comment: You can call once `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` - that's it. I'll update answer.

Comment: I know, I'm just not sure whether it is required to call `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` or `entry.DetectChanges()` explicitly. For example here it is called automatically: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ysaIor

Comment: Attach is different thing, in this case you already instructed ChangeTracker what has been changed.

Comment: IOW, call `DetectChanges` always.

Comment: Not really. Attach starts tracking entity as unmodified. I have some properties after the attach and the changes are detected without calling detect changes.

DetectChanges() might be expensive, so it's worth to know when to call it explicitelly.

Comment: Because they all can be marked as modified.

Comment: But only those I have modified after the attach are marked as modified.
If I just attach entity and don't modify a property, the `IsModified` will be false for that property. Try to comment out line 59 and see the outpit. I think you mistook Attach() for Add()

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/release/6.0/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs#L1044

Comment: Well,  I have missed such thing. Looks like Entry returned by ChangeTracker is has already detected changes. Updated answer.

Comment: I'm doing something similar, but I've noticed that for an entity in `Modified` state all its properties will give you `.IsModified` as `true`. Any idea how to "easily" detect which properties have actually changed?